# Why is the text coming over as white in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am stumped. After running the following script the text color is coming over white. How do I set the text to come over as Black? Would it be done when the text is being replaced or in the build request? I would appreciate any assistance with this issue.

```
function getDataSheet() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
 var range = sheet
   .getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
   .getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
   var link = range[i][1].toString();

   if (link != []) {
     var quarterlySheet = SlidesApp.openByUrl(link);
     var id = quarterlySheet.getId();

     var requests = buildRequest(range[i]);

     replaceData(requests, id);
   }
 }
}

function buildRequest(data) {
 var courses = data[2].toString();
 var teachers = data[3].toString();
 var students = data[4].toString();
 var assignments = data[5].toString();
 var discussions = data[6].toString();
 var attachments = data[7].toString();
 var media = data[8].toString();
 var datedt = new Date(data[9]);
 var date = ((datedt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + datedt.getDate()).toString();

 if (date === "NaN/NaN") {
   date = data[9].toString();
 }
 var topic = data[10].toString();
 var format = data[11].toString();
 var impacts = data[12].toString();

//  return [
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1C%' },
//        replaceText: courses
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1T%' },
//        replaceText: teachers
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1S%' },
//        replaceText: students
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1A%' },
//        replaceText: assignments
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1D%' },
//        replaceText: discussions
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1F%' },
//        replaceText: attachments
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1M%' },
//        replaceText: media
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1Date%' },
//        replaceText: date
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1Focus%' },
//        replaceText: topic
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1Format%' },
//        replaceText: format
//      }
//    },
//    {
//      replaceAllText: {
//        containsText: { text: '%Q1Interaction%' },
//        replaceText: impacts
//      }
//    }
//  ];


}


function replaceData(requests, id) {
 try {
   Logger.log(requests);
   Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, id);
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log(e.toString());
 }
}
```

I would appreciate any assistance with this issue.

Comment: Please provide a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Please describe what your script does and what have you attempted to find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Please provide access to your sheet.

Comment: Here is an updated link. My bad. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18zusMyH_yfMPaR0ez98M1J33SFXDjA5OvMQu6sGOumE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KyleCole This is a lot. Please minimise your code to a minimal, reproducible example as it is difficult to understand everything that is going on here.